# iPhone built in plugins for Safari?

Tags: iphone

I've been using my iphone to surf the internet a couple of times, and I've noticed that some websites had some plugins on their site, I've been trying to find these for my own website but couldn't find them.

The plugin I'm interested in is kind of a 'Coverflow' effect,
it's completely based on the touch screen, and looked about the same on every site I've seen it on. that's why I'm assuming it's a.. built in plugin or something like that.
I've also noticed that these sites have an iphone styled toolbar and menus, well I'd be grateful if you could help me find that plugin, 
Would also be nice if you could explain about it a little or show me more plugins that are available out there for the iPhone's safari

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any plugin in Mobile Safari, but you can use some Frameworks to build apps with touch-events. For example:

- http://jqtouch.com/
- http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/

These frameworks often offer much features, which you can use to let your web app look like a normal iPhone-App.